# Redirecting middleware route not working in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I'm trying to create a middleware that if the user has been disabled then they can't access the website. The problem I'm having is that instead of going to the login route it keeps trying to go to the home route.

My middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(request()->user()->enabled == true)
    {
        return $next($request);
    }else{
        return redirect()->route('login')->with('error', 'Your account has been disabled.');
    }
}
```

My home route

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home')->middleware('enabled');
```

Comment: because they are 'logged' in and the 'login' route is protected by the guest middleware that redirects logged in users away to the '/home' route

Answer (score 1):

In order for the middleware to work as expected you have to logout the user so the middlware will look like below:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(request()->user()->enabled == true)
    {
        return $next($request);
    }else{
        request()->user()->logout() // logout the user
        return redirect()->route('login')->with('error', 'Your account has been disabled.');
    }
}
```